# iOS Simulator: Application can't terminate correcly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios-simulator

I have an application that when terminated needs to synchronize the content of a sqlite database.
To know when the application is terminating, I put a breakpoint in the app delegate's applicationWillTerminate: method.But the debugger never steps there.
I know two methods to terminate the application:

1. Like I do in the iPhone: Keep touching the application icon until it starts trembling, the I click on 'x';
2. Stopping the debugger.

None of these two methods cause the debugger to step in the applicationWillTerminate: method of my app delegate.
If I use the first method I even get an exception:  I receive SIGKILL right in this line:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

It seems like the simulator launches SIGKILL even if there isn't a handler for that signal.
The last message called is mach_msg_trap.

Comment: Read the documentation: "For applications that do not support background execution or are linked against iOS 3.x or earlier, this method is always called when the user quits the application. For applications that support background execution, this method is generally not called when the user quits the application because the application simply moves to the background in that case. However, this method may be called in situations where the application is running in the background (not suspended) and the system needs to terminate it for some reason."

Comment: @MikeWeller You should put that as an answer.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation

> For applications that do not support background execution or are
>   linked against iOS 3.x or earlier, this method is always called when
>   the user quits the application. For applications that support
>   background execution, this method is generally not called when the
>   user quits the application because the application simply moves to the
>   background in that case. However, this method may be called in
>   situations where the application is running in the background (not
>   suspended) and the system needs to terminate it for some reason.

You probably want `applicationWillResignActive:`.

Comment: A little doubt here: am I obliged to load the data from the database when application becomes active, and to synchronize it when it enters in background? Can't I know when the application terminates?

Comment: No. If the app is in the background and gets terminated to free up memory (for example), you will not be notified. You can only handle events like `applicationDidEnterBackground:` or `applicationWillResignActive:`.

Comment: You should also make sure that the sync is not taking too much time otherwise the OS will kill the app before you have finished writing to the DB. It would probably be a good idea to ask the OS for extra time to finish background processing which will give you a maximum of 10 mins to synchronize your DB. It helps in preventing unnecessary crashes AND makes sure your data remains consistent